# How to compute A* star with custom heuristic in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path, a-star

I am trying to compute the shortest path length between two nodes with a custom heuristic. The heuristic measures the weighted shortest path length between two nodes plus by the number of nodes within the shortest path. Think about a transportation problem where I need to find the shortest path between two cities in a city network. The shortest path is the path that has minimum total distance (in days unit) and the minimum number of transit in a city (in days unit).

I am trying to use networkx with a_star_path_length function. Here is what I've already tried:

```
def distance(a,b):
    return ( nx.dijkstra_path_length(G,a,b, 'day') + len(nx.dijkstra_path(G, a, b)) )

nx.astar_path_length(G, 'A', 'F', heuristic=distance, weight='day')
```

Suppose, the weights for every edge in a graph with six nodes are as follow:

```
A,B --> 1 day
B,C --> 1 day
C,D --> 1 day
D,F --> 1 day
A,E --> 4 day
E,F --> 1 day
```

For every visited node, I need to spend 1 day.

Therefore, the shortest path between city A and city F is as follow: 
    A --> E --> F

the result should be (4 + 1) + (1 + 1) = 7.

The path A-B-C-D-F may have the shortest distance. But due to a number of transits, they are not the shortest path anymore.

I tried my function with a_star function, but the algorithm still prefers route A-B-C-D-F, instead A-E-F.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're trying to modify the heuristic, not the actual graph weighting. The A* algorithm actually does return a least-weight path the same way Djikstra's algorithm does, it just can do this much faster than Djikstra since it isn't doing a random breadth-first search, but has a heuristic to help guide it in the right direction in the graph. Importantly, it still finds a least weight path, regardless of what the heuristic is†.

The way to fix this for your problem is to incorporate transit number into the weight. I believe this should just amount to adding 1 (or however you want to weight a hop) to every single weight in your graph.

†Usually, I believe there is an exception for certain heuristic properties.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Now I understand better what the heuristic means in A* algorithm. Thanks also for the suggestion. Turn out, the problem could be simplified by modifying the weight!